# Tikz snake arrows

Tags: tikz-styles

As suggested by the manual, I use the following code the draw snake lines. I defined a `snake arrow/.style`, it works perfect when I apply it to a single `edge`'. But it does not work if I apply it to a grouped `\draw` or `\path`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{snake arrow/.style=
{->,
decorate,
decoration={snake,amplitude=.4mm,segment length=2mm,post length=1mm}}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {0,...,4}{
  \node (p\i) at (2\i, 4\i+1){}; % random node
  }
  \draw%[snake arrow] %this does not work
  (p0) edge[snake arrow] (p1)% this works
  (p2) edge (p4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can change the `edge` path to a `to` path. Then it works.

Comment: @KevinC I expect two snake arrows, but the `to` result is two snakes with only one arrow.

Comment: Or, add the `[snake arrow]` option to both of the `edge`s.

Comment: @HarishKumar That is the point I intended to ask. If I have a great deal of snake arrows to draw, I would like to have a *grouped* solution.

Comment: How about this: put `\tikzset{every edge/.style={draw,snake arrow}}` somewhere in the TikZ picture, and just use the `edge` operation as usual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The options you present to `\draw` will be applied to the first segment alone. You can group all your snake edges in to a scope and put

```
every edge/.style={draw,snake arrow}
```

as the option to the scope to make it local.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{snake arrow/.style=
{->,
decorate,
decoration={snake,amplitude=.4mm,segment length=2mm,post length=1mm}},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every edge/.append style = {snake arrow}]
  \foreach \i in {0,...,4}{
  \node (p\i) at (2\i, 4\i+1){}; % random node
  }
  \draw %this does not work
  (p0) edge (p1)% this works
  (p2) edge (p4);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
  \foreach \i in {0,...,4}{
  \node (p\i) at (2\i, 4\i+1){}; % random node
  }
  \draw %this does not work
  (p0) edge (p1)% this works
  (p2) edge (p4);
\end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hah, you beat me on this one `:)`

Comment: So there are two solutions provided, `every edge/.append style={snake arrow}` or `every edge/.style={draw, snake arrow}`. It seems work fine, thanks you guys.

Comment: @KevinC hehe. I was writing my answer first ;-)

Comment: @MaMing `every edge/.append style={snake arrow}` is better as it will append the style. Hence if you define any special thing previously, it won't be discarded. `every edge/.style={draw, snake arrow}` will over write previous settings.