# How to draw a figure that can be pointed at the letter?

Tags: pgfplots, floats, text

I'm sorry for my bad title since I don't know how to exactly describe my question.
Normally I draw my figure with another tool (e.g., diagram.net), export to .eps file and then put it to latex. By this way, all elements in the figure is unselectable.
I'm able to draw basic figure with tikzpicture and I think that this package  is not a solution for this problem.

I saw in some papers, people draw figure consisting texts that can be selected by mouse?
For example in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.03260.pdf), Figure 1, all the text is selectable?
[image]
How is that possible?
Please give me a recomendation or a tutorial for this?

I'm appreciated for your help.

Comment: You can do such images using TikZ, why should you not? On the other hand, if you make it with another application, export it as PDF and import the PDF, the text should still be selectable with the mouse, if is was in the original, exported PDF. So this is nothing strange. Only if the text is either exported as curves or as bitmap, the text is no longer selectable.

Comment: If you create a tikz-diagram with some textual content, and compile it to a .pdf, those texts ARE selectable in the pdf. Does this answer your qeustion?

Comment: BTW, if you check the documentproperties of the pdf you point to, it says: used Latex with hyperref. Taking the apperance into account, the graphic most likely was created by tikz (it's not a convincing argument, though). // See e.g. https://texample.net/tikz/examples/database-decimation-process/ or https://texample.net/tikz/examples/system-combination/ and other examples from the tikz gallery. // Or review the overleaf gallery: https://de.overleaf.com/gallery?q=diagram

Comment: Or see this tikz-solution, which is close to some detail of your complex drawing: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353129/245790

Comment: Excuse me but do you mean that the complex figure like above is possible to be made by TikZ? I personally don't believe. 
If Yes, so we need to embed external images to TikZ figure, similar like this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115087/how-can-i-embed-an-external-image-within-a-tikzpicture-environment
@MS-SPO please help, thanks!

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176280/image-link-clickable-in-non-white-areas-excluding-the-background/261071?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C21.3347#261071

Comment: @Van-TienPHAM, as this is no discussion board just a few remarks. If you need to chat, open a chat on this site.// It‘s not big. It reuses similar elements, like the green and orange matrices-> candidates for macros. Positioning: can be done. Text can be placed. Lines can be drawn, even in silly shapes. So: I suggest to look into the minimal introduction. Look for tikz on ctan.org, and start coding \tikz{ } statements inside LaTeX docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some answers to your question

> How is that possible? Please give me a recomendation or a tutorial for
> this?

---

#1 The standard link is to the [TIKZ/pgf package at ctan](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf). The documentation comes in two flavours:

- a small tutorial (Minimal introduction)
- the huge manual.

I recommend to start with the minimal one, though you can also follow the huge manual nicely from front to back. But the better way is to use it as a source for deeper understanding.

---

#2 The University of Leipzig has a very nice and compact [tutorial](https://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/%7Ehellmund/LaTeX/pgf-tut.pdf) , giving you the relevant syntax with some examples.

But also Overleaf has a [5-part-tutorial](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ%3A_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_1)%E2%80%94Basic_Drawing) for you.

---

#3 Finally, if you prefer videos, have a try on youtube. E.g. this one sounds promissing: [How to make beautiful math graphics using Tikz & LaTeX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQugbYq0BVA) .

---

Besides that, a number of links made in the comments point you to examples with elegant and less elegant code examples, which you can use as a source of inspiration.

Don't hesitate to try this sites [tag-search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags) : enter tikz into the search field and make your choice.